# SMIME email decryption using a private key - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl, decryption

I have an encrypted .eml file and a private key. I've looked it up a lot on the internet but couldn't find a way to decrypt the email using OpenSSL. I've tried this command:
`smime -decrypt -in encrypted.eml -inkey privatekey.key -out decrypted.eml`
and each time I get this error:

`OpenSSL> smime -decrypt -in encrypted.eml -inkey privatekey.key -out decrypted.eml`
`No recipient certificate or key specified`
`smime: Use -help for summary.`

I have also tried converting the private key to a .pem file but it still displays the same message. both files are in the same folder as the openssl.exe application is, before that I couldn't get it to work at all.

**I clearly am doing something wrong, what is it exactly?**

Comment: `-inkey` is an option and all options (must) **begin with a hyphen**. The privatekey file does need to be in PEM _format_ inside, but it doesn't need to be _named_ `.pem` unless you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `openssl cms` instead of `openssl smime`.  See https://www.misterpki.com/openssl-cms/ for a good example.

Comment: I've tried that but I still get the same error: `No recipient certificate or key specified`